# Django download a file

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to using Django and I am trying to develop a website where the user is able to upload a number of excel files, these files are then stored in a media folder **Webproject/project/media.**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('project/upload_successful.html')
    else:
        form = FileForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('project/create.html', args)
```

The document is then displayed in a list along with any other document they have uploaded, which you can click into and it will displays basic info about them and the name of the excelfile they have uploaded. From here I want to be able to download the same excel file again using the link:

```
 <a  href="/project/download"> Download Document </a>
```

My urls are

```
 urlpatterns = [

              url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
                                          template_name="project/project.html")),
              url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model=Post, template_name="project/post.html")),
              url(r'^upload/$', upload),
              url(r'^download/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

          ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

but I get the error, serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document root'. can anyone explain how to fix this?

**OR**

Explain how I can get the uploaded files to to be selected and served using

```
def download(request):
    file_name = #get the filename of desired excel file
    path_to_file = #get the path of desired excel file
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
    return response
```

Comment: can you include the code from the `serve` view?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You missed underscore in argument document**_**root. But it's bad idea to use `serve` in production. Use something like this instead:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

Comment: Doesn't this let users download any file on the server by using a `path` like `../../some/other/path/secrets.txt`?

Comment: @DonKirkby likely, I never used this code. It would be reasonable to limit allowed symbols in URL or add something like `if ROOT_DIR not in os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, path)): raise PermissionDenied` to view.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust this method so that the user will download .exe files for example?

Comment: @Keselme yes. You only need to change `content_type` to 'application/octet-stream'.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, thank you. If the file is of .apk type, should I use 'application/vnd.android.package-archive' as content-type, or is 'application/octet-stream' still good?

Comment: @Keselme it's always better to use a more specific type. Use 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: I'm late to the party but: what is the path argument for? And could I use this to download a powerpoint file?

Comment: why sould we use `open`? why should python read the file(s), by doing this, there is two possible errors maybe. first maybe the file is not such kind that python could `open/read`, and second it's an unnecessary loading in memory.(sorry for my english)

Comment: If you want to download with default app, just change ```content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel"``` to ```content_type="application/default"```

Comment: How can this be achieved but still using ```return render(request, template, context)```. I want to change the template to tell the user that ABC has been downloaded and for this I need to send ```context``` back to the template.

Comment: Why not just provide the file in the html template and let the user download on demand? Django supports this. Is there an advantage to the proposed solution rather just use `href="{{file.url}}" download`?

Answer (score 66):

You can add "download" attribute inside your tag to download files.

```
<a  href="/project/download" download> Download Document </a>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Damn this is so easy to implement, I wonder why so less upvotes!

Comment: Because it doesn't work with Django. Django processes "/project/download" as a URL... so if `/project/myfile.pdf` doesn't resolve to a URL... the GET request will give a 404 in Django - even though the html is marked as a download.

Comment: you can use it with Django doing: return format_html('<a href="/media/{0}" download>{0}</a>', value)

Comment: Its working for me in djago
<a href="{{ obj.file_field_name.url }}" download>Download</a>

Comment: @Hanny are you sure for download tag didn't solve your problem. Maybe you can check your MEDIA_ROOT folder settings.

Comment: Worked for me as well, I just needed to change the path in  `upload_to` attribute in the `FileField` on my `models.py`. My template look like this: `<a href="{{obj_name.field_name.url}}" download>`

Comment: This one worked for me also using <a href="{% static 'path/to/file' %} download>Download</a>. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine in development environment, curious to see how this will work during deployment and serving from server for example. Either way, in my case I just have a model in which i store the directories with ```models.FileField(storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT), upload_to='experiments', blank=True)```. Later on these can be called upon in html for download as: ```{% if 'experiments' in every_column %}
    <td> <a href="/media/{{ every_column }}" download>{{ every_column }}</a></td>```

Answer (score 43):

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects):

In view.py Implement function like,

```
def download(request, id):
    obj = your_model_name.objects.get(id=id)
    filename = obj.model_attribute_name.path
    response = FileResponse(open(filename, 'rb'))
    return response
```

Comment: This seems better than the accepted answer, thanks! Does this work with nginx too somehow?

Comment: Inside the reference, but worth mentioning, is that no context manager is needed: "The file will be closed automatically, so don’t open it with a context manager."

Answer (score 8):

When you upload a file using `FileField`, the file will have a URL that you can use to point to the file and use HTML `download` attribute to download that file you can simply do this.

`models.py`

The model.py looks like this

```
class CsvFile(models.Model):
    csv_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

`views.py`

#csv upload

```
class CsvUploadView(generic.CreateView):

   model = CsvFile
   fields = ['csv_file']
   template_name = 'upload.html'
```

#csv download

```
class CsvDownloadView(generic.ListView):

    model = CsvFile
    fields = ['csv_file']
    template_name = 'download.html'
```

Then in your templates.

#Upload template

`upload.html`

```
<div class="container">
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

#download template

`download.html`

```
  {% for document in object_list %}

     <a href="{{ document.csv_file.url }}" download  class="btn btn-dark float-right">Download</a>

  {% endfor %}
```

I did not use forms, just rendered model but either way, **FileField** is there and it will work the same.

Comment: After more than three year this was still straight forward for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've found Django's `FileField` to be really helpful for letting users upload and download files. The Django documentation has a section on [managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/files/). You can store some information about the file in a table, along with a `FileField` that points to the file itself. Then you can list the available files by searching the table.

Answer (score 3):

1. `<a href='/your-download-view/' download>Download</a>`
2. In your view:

```py
from django.http import FileResponse

def download(request):
    # pre-processing, authorizations, etc.
    # ...
    return FileResponse(open(path_to_file, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: what if the return is with a different extension, for example I have a pdf file and then I process the file into JSON then I download the result and save it to my computer?

Answer (score 2):

@Biswadp's solution worked greatly for me

In your static folder, make sure to have the desired files you would like the user to download

In your HTML template, your code should look like this :

```
<a href="{% static 'Highlight.docx' %}"> Download </a>
```

Comment: Make sure you load static at the top of the page {% load static %}, right after: {% block content %}. This is thew simplest approach and it worked super well and fast for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using the below approach makes everything less secure since any user can access any user's file.

```
<a  href="/project/download" download> Download Document </a>
```

Using the below approach makes no sense since Django only handles one requests at the time (unless you are using gunicorn or something else), and believe me, the below approach takes a lot of time to complete.

```
def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

So what is the optimum solution?
Use Nginx authenticated routes. When requesting a file from Nginx you can make a request to a route and depending on the HTTP response Nginx allows to denies that request. This makes it very secure and also scalable and performant.
You can ready about more [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/#:%7E:text=To%20perform%20authentication%2C%20NGINX%20makes,403%20%2C%20the%20access%20is%20denied.)

Answer (score 2):

```
import mimetypes
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(json_file_path)
    
if os.path.exists(json_file_path):
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh, content_type=mime_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % 'config.json'
        return response
raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple using html like this downloads the file mentioned using static keyword

```
<a href="{% static 'bt.docx' %}" class="btn btn-secondary px-4 py-2 btn-sm">Download CV</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.settings.py:

```
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
#Media
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

2.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

3.in template:

```
<a href="{{ file.url }}" download>Download File.</a>
```

## Work and test in django >=3

for more detail use this link:
https://youtu.be/MpDZ34mEJ5Y

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a FileField in the model, this is the way I do it:

```
    try:
        download_file = PrintingFile.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk_file', 0))
        return FileResponse(download_file.file.open(), as_attachment=True)
    except PrintingFile.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

More [here](https://nemecek.be/blog/165/django-how-to-let-user-download-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

```
{% if quote.myfile %}
    <div class="">
        <a role="button" 
            href="{{ quote.myfile.url }}"
            download="{{ quote.myfile.url }}"
            class="btn btn-light text-dark ml-0">
            Download attachment
        </a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hafe upload your file in media than:

`media` 
example-input-file.txt

`views.py`

```py
def download_csv(request):    
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'example-input-file.txt')    
    if os.path.exists(file_path):    
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:    
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")    
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)    
            return response
```

`urls.py`

```
path('download_csv/', views.download_csv, name='download_csv'),
```

`download.html`

```html
a href="{% url 'download_csv' %}" download=""
```