# How to serve a text file at root with Django

Tags: django, url

I got a site, say it's "www.site.com". I need to serve a text file at the root, so that "www.site.com/text.txt" will show up.

I read through this answer: [Django download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392510/django-download-a-file), and I used the "download" function.

However I am at a loss how to configure the URL. Can someone help me out?

Say I put this this into my url.py,

```
url('^(?P<path>.*)/$', san.views.FileDownload.as_view()),
```

This then supersedes all my other url patterns and render them useless. How do I make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it as the last urlpattern in your `urls.py` to ensure it doesn't sccop up everything. It should not have the trailing `/` either, i.e.

```
url('^(?P<path>.*)/?$', san.views.FileDownload.as_view()),
```

This will match the request "***/YOUR_FILE.txt***", and is also case-insensitive.

```
url(r'^(?i)YOUR_FILE.txt$', san.views.FileDownload.as_view()),
```

Comment: I actually know the EXACT file name to expect. How would you suggest I change the pattern?