# TypeError at /1 argument should be string, bytes or integer, not Download

Tags: python, django

I want to serve my download files from the media files and the files are being uploaded through from the admin. I tried something and I'm getting this error

```
TypeError at /1

argument should be string, bytes or integer, not Download
```

below are my codes.

**view.py**

```
    def download(request, download_id):
        downloading = Download.objects.get(pk=download_id)
        if os.path.exists(downloading):
        with open(downloading, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="text/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(downloading)
            response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(downloading)
            return response
        pdf.closed
    raise Http404
```

**url.py**

```
    url(r'^(?P<download_id>\d+)$', views.download, name='download'),
```

**html link**

```
    <a href="{% url 'peruse:download' download.id %}" class="btn btn-generic btn-sm" role="button">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

**model.py**

```
    class Download(models.Model):
        pdf_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
        pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to='Downloads/%d-%m-%Y/', blank = False,)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
        is_visible = models.BooleanField(default = True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.pdf_name
```

and this view handles the upload.

```
    def upload(request):
        uploading = Download.objects.filter(is_visible = True)
        context = { 'uploading' : uploading }
        fillAuthContext(request, context)
        return render(request, 'library/resources.html', context)
```

Comment: Please format your code and the whole post it's really hard to read

Comment: formatted thank you

Comment: was trying to work with what i saw here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392510/django-download-a-file. please feel free to correct any error you find. am not too good using django. thank you

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?  Is it the `open`?  Please post your entire error message and traceback.  Where does `Download` come from?

Comment: Please be so polite and read the [tour]. Thanks and other non-essentials that don't help understand your issue (e.g. "I am new here") do not belong in your post. Use a spell checker that catches errors like using "i" instead of "I".

Comment: os.stat(path)
TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not Download
[27/May/2017 09:04:48] "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 500 69362

Comment: The `downloading` should be your `download file path` string, not `Download` object.

Comment: ok. the reason why the code is not working is maybe i my not be getting it right at all. how can i generate a view that will serve download from my media files. the media files are uploaded through the admin page.

Comment: please share your `Download` model

Comment: the model has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your help. i was able to come up with something that worked with your ideas.

view.py

```
    def download(request, download_id):
        downloading = Download.objects.get(pk=download_id)
        path = downloading.pdf_file.name
        file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type="text/pdf")
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
                response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
                return response
            pdf.closed
        raise Http404
```

its now working. users can now be able to download file

Comment: your idea is exactly same as my answer, just I am not sure your `Download` folder is in your `MDEIA_ROOT`, I thought it is in your project root folder.

Comment: yes. its the same. that's how i got the idea on how to direct it correctly. thank you so much

Comment: if it is helpful, and it is the right solution, then mark it as accept answer, people take hours to work for your issue, help to direct the right way, please respect their time and effort they put. :)

Comment: Yahhhh. I tried thicking it the day i posted it. But i was not permitted to do so till after two day. But its done now. Thank you

Comment: hi Tiny D. I can please ask you some questions personally concerning django. my mail is lord.mila@yahoo.com thank you

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass the parameter as your `download file path` string, not `Download` object, just change your `download` function to :

```
def download(request, download_id):
    downloading = Download.objects.get(pk=download_id)
    file_path = downloading.pdf_file.name
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="text/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
            return response
        pdf.closed
    raise Http404
```

I have verified your code, this will work for you:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/peruse/download/1` (`download_id=1` here) will give you the first file:

[image]

**Update:**

make sure your root `yourproject/urls.py` is like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^peruse/',include('peruse.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And `yourproject/peruse/urls.py` is like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^download/(?P<download_id>\d+)$', views.download, name='download'),
]
```

And make sure you have already uploaded the file.

Comment: thanks tiny, but its raising an error;                                                    Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/1
Raised by:  peruse.views.download

Comment: I think there is some issue with your `urls`, check my updated answer.