# Why is my docx file content spoiled while saving and downloading it on Django webpage?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to build a Django webpage, where the user uploads docx files, edites them and downloads as new docx files. When the file is downloaded, the content is spoiled.

The views.py function is the following:

```
from docx import Document

def edit_file(request, upload_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(DocFile, id=upload_id)
    document = Document(instance.agreement)

        # here is some code to edit the docx file

        file_name = '{}.doc'.format(contract_name)
        response = HttpResponse(document, content_type='application/msword')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(file_name)
        document.save(response)
        return response
    return render(request, 'uploads/file_detail.html', {
        'variables': variables, 'form_field': form_field
    })
```

I edit this kind of content file [image: this kind of content file]
And get this spoiled content in the new file[image: new file content]
Is it possible to get downloaded the edited file but not the content be spoiled in this way? If no, what other ways are possible?

Comment: you have to explain what `Document` is and what `document.save(response)` in particular is doing. Which package are you using? And what is "spoiled"? You should pass a file in the `HttpResponse` (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392510/django-download-a-file)), I don't know if a `Document` instance is the actual file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392510/django-download-a-file)

Comment: How is the content spoiled exactly?

Comment: I added what is 'Document'. I use python-docx to edit and save files.

Comment: And also added the old and new files contents

Comment: Actually, I use your mentioned examples, and it works. Only the document content is spoiled. I change the `content_type` in `response = HttpResponse(document, content_type='application/msword')` but get the same result ((.