# Creating a downloadable Link with pk in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, url, view

I want to be able to click a button that triggers a download, for a better understanding, my codes are below

```
    import mimetypes

    From wsgiref.util import Filewrapper

    def audio_download (request, pk):
        download =get_object_or_404(Audio,pk=pk)

        file =download.audio.audio.url.strip('/')
        wrapper = FileWrapper(open(file, 'rb'))
        response= HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/force-download')
        response ['Content-Disposition]="attachment; filename="+os.path.basename(file)
        Print ('response')
        return response
```

Then my url:

```
  url (r'^audio/download/(P<pk>\d+)/$, views.audio_download, name= 'audio_download')
```

Then lastly, HTML

```
    {%for audio in audio%}
    <a href = "audio/download/{{audio.id}}">{{audio.title}}</a></center>
    {%endfor%}
```

Comment: I think your question was already answered for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394206/2047157

Comment: Inside the function `audio_download` use debugger like `ipdb` to check what is going on.

Comment: very probably unrelated, but you should not hardcode your url (nor use relative url path FWIW) - [use the `{% url %}` templatetag instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: @darkless, thanks, but there's no pk (primary key) used and what does file_path really means in the code..  thanks

Comment: you need to get `file_path` (as in the link) from the `download` object you got, which I guess could be download.audio.path. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: @darkless, thanks for the link which was really helpful, I followed the thread in the Link and landed at Page not found (404)... Thanks

Comment: @darkless am really grateful, files like PDF, doc works fine with the reference Link you shared with me, but file like mp4 videos doesn't seem to download.. please help

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `HttpResponse`:

```
response= HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/force-download')
```

you can try using [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects):

```
from django.http import FileResponse

response= FileResponse(open(file, 'rb'), content_type='application/force-download')
response ['Content-Disposition]="attachment; filename="+os.path.basename(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to my question, I felt I should share with other users who have similar issues

```
import mimetypes
From wsgiref.util import Filewrapper


def audio_download (request, path):
    audio_path =os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
    response= HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type='application/mp3')
    response ['Content-Disposition]="inline; filename="+os.path.basename(file_path)
    Print ('response')
    return response
raise Http404
```

The remaining of my template and URLs remains the same